# Remember li active state when loading to different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code below:

```
    <ul id="profileList" class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/signature')?>">修改个人签名档</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/location')?>">修改个人居住地</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/education')?>">修改个人学校专业</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Also here's the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // store url for current page as global variable
    current_page = document.location.href

    // apply selected states depending on current page
    if (current_page.index(/signature/)) {
        $("ul#profileList li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
    } else if (current_page.match(/location/)) {
        $("ul#profileList li:eq(1)").addClass('active');
    } else if (current_page.match(/education/)) {
        $("ul#profileList li:eq(2)").addClass('active');
    } else { // don't mark any nav links as selected
        $("ul#profileList li").removeClass('active');
    };

    });
</script>
```

When I click the second and third li item, they work well. But when I click the first item,
the item is not becoming active. What's the wrong and why?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if (current_page.index(/signature/)) {
```

Change to

```
if (current_page.match(/signature/)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `String.prototype.index` doesn't exist. Perhaps you wanted to use the `indexOf` method.

```
if (current_page.indexOf('signature') !== -1) {}
```

Also, do not use the `String.prototype.match` function when you just want to know if there's a match or not, use the `RegExp.prototype.test` function.

```
if (/education/.test('education')) { /*matches*/ }
```

However in your case, you could use the `match` method and instead of discarding the match, use it at your advantage:

```
var sections = ['signature', 'location', 'education'],
    match = document.location.href.match(new RegExp(sections.join('|'), 'i')),
    selectorSuffix = match? ':eq(' + sections.indexOf(match[0].toLowerCase()) + ')' : '';

$('ul#profileList li' + selectorSuffix)[(match? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class']('active');
```